# Is this set meet the vector space criteria?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

Given a set S = {(a, b) | a, b ∈ ℝ} and have a sum definition as of vector space R2, and a multiplication scalar as k(a, b) = ((k.a) + 1, kb) whereas k is a scalar.

Given those circumstances is set S a vector space or not?

In the definition from my lecturer, k.u = k(a, b) has to be (k.a, k.b) thus, k.u ∈ S. That concludes S is not a vector space because it doesn't meet the axiom of scalar multiplication, note that k.a+1 != k.a

But, what confused me is k.a + 1 is also a real number(a, b ∈ ℝ). So in my opinion,

k(a, b) = ((k.a) + 1, k.b) is also ∈ S

Which one is true?

Comment: $k(l(a,b))\not =(kl)(a,b)$

Comment: @Fan with explanation perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k(l(a,b))=k(la+1,lb)=(kla+k+1, klb),$ while $(kl)(a,b)=(kla+1,klb)$.

Comment: I see, you're a man of mathematic language as well. thanks btw

Comment: So S is not a vector space because it didn't meet the scalar multiplication axiom?

Comment: @RefoIlmiya I think so